# SqlDataSource configure programmatically from code

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am using in my app in SqlDataSource to fill  a dropdownlist ,i configure it in the web design in Visual studio.

i want that this dropdownlist will change dynamically by a couple of table in the sql.

it is possible to change the  SqlDataSource programmatically from code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource(connectionString);
source.SelectCommand = String.Format("SELECT id, type FROM {0}" selectedTable)
source.DataBind();
```